# Incorrect behaviour or numpy.argmax function (closed, my fail here)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of length 500, and try to get the position of its largest element.

```
> type(arr)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
> numpy.max(arr)
0.99841506 # the largest value is here the last one, so its position must be 499, but
> numpy.argmax(arr)
249 # argmax returns 249, which is 0.9814647
```

What's wrong with this array? in other cases argmax works correctly.
Here is the "unnormal" array itself:

```
[ 0.88909795  0.88978061  0.89034673  0.89087944  0.89145257  0.89210397
  0.89276644  0.89334441  0.89382041  0.89412578  0.89432752  0.8944299
  0.89463225  0.89497062  0.89532122  0.89564772  0.8958474   0.89592464
  0.89630575  0.89698798  0.89769293  0.89848076  0.89930387  0.90013392
  0.90104787  0.90194464  0.90295569  0.9039833   0.9050346   0.90606623
  0.90710517  0.90819266  0.90923895  0.91037811  0.91156073  0.91300442
  0.91446512  0.91584151  0.91715882  0.91845024  0.91955421  0.92089298
  0.92244761  0.92398027  0.92523805  0.92643114  0.92755521  0.92864628
  0.92981656  0.93095717  0.93208001  0.93326082  0.93442172  0.93567889
  0.93666403  0.93801784  0.93904143  0.94014266  0.94127314  0.94247457
  0.94350104  0.94388245  0.9446991   0.94563049  0.94652052  0.94740291
  0.94813891  0.94865294  0.94928902  0.94985706  0.95011467  0.95032619
  0.95047542  0.95055906  0.95068319  0.95087543  0.95134286  0.95219489
  0.95271328  0.95308582  0.95367633  0.95438522  0.95537771  0.95626897
  0.95709159  0.95805329  0.95904842  0.96008088  0.96115256  0.96221983
  0.96315547  0.9641299   0.96526232  0.96634076  0.9673133   0.96829591
  0.9692317   0.97008387  0.97076741  0.97145813  0.97215305  0.97273013
  0.97324447  0.97384943  0.97444085  0.97502589  0.97565676  0.9762706
  0.97698153  0.9779038   0.97879313  0.97943701  0.98006739  0.98063262
  0.98096896  0.98130123  0.98159047  0.98172486  0.98169341  0.98158367
  0.98150869  0.9815271   0.98153536  0.98164806  0.98173003  0.98171431
  0.98173717  0.98167403  0.98145793  0.98120804  0.98106709  0.98101609
  0.98112061  0.98114241  0.98098263  0.98089001  0.98085913  0.98073206
  0.98045551  0.98013516  0.9799087   0.97975682  0.97967519  0.97963055
  0.97955903  0.97957455  0.97960247  0.97958315  0.97948352  0.9793838
  0.97931257  0.97913527  0.97756488  0.97743783  0.97723032  0.9771425
  0.97692371  0.97670625  0.97671619  0.9772266   0.97849404  0.97935737
  0.98037385  0.98136674  0.98229204  0.98313426  0.98371021  0.98423502
  0.98475514  0.98519817  0.9853992   0.98522209  0.98544847  0.98585939
  0.9857425   0.9857368   0.98581936  0.98587366  0.98570029  0.98555498
  0.98545724  0.98516041  0.98520702  0.98522651  0.98507088  0.98477696
  0.98442745  0.98415864  0.98401446  0.98404856  0.98404806  0.98411621
  0.98416166  0.98438146  0.98455107  0.98476666  0.98488303  0.98484396
  0.98465454  0.98457754  0.9845227   0.98420963  0.98379581  0.98339187
  0.98296063  0.98215673  0.9818166   0.98136827  0.98092174  0.98064912
  0.98051665  0.98154758  0.98175672  0.98187866  0.98201024  0.98213502
  0.98217471  0.98243727  0.98261784  0.98269089  0.98292136  0.98307152
  0.98319756  0.98345249  0.98336651  0.98425455  0.98513982  0.98601273
  0.98669306  0.98816828  0.98959878  0.99017499  0.99073479  0.99148809
  0.99195023  0.99247333  0.99292418  0.99330445  0.99376024  0.99435036
  0.99501503  0.99565791  0.9943401   0.99495361  0.99539686  0.99585094
  0.99646274  0.99703564  0.99765937  0.99841506]
```

Can u please explain it? I dont need this very array, but i'd like to be sure in numpy.argmax correctness.

PS.

Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb 23 2014, 01:28:31) [GCC 4.7.3] on linux2

numpy: 1.8.0-r1

Answer (score 2):

Your array has 250 elements. They are indexed `[0]` to `[249]`. The last element is at `[249]`, which it correctly found for you.

Comment: Oh, really! Thanks!
It seems i need some rest :)

Comment: Most programming languages that I can think of use element `[0]` as the first element. The two exceptions I can think of are `Fortran` and `Visual Basic`, which start their arrays at `1`.

Comment: @Cyber OP knows about 0-indexed arrays (see comment "the largest value is here the last one, so its position must be 499" in the code sample). The problem was getting the number of elements in the array wrong. This answer, and the associated question, should be deleted.